# nmap reports IP address is active, when the network device is turned off?

Tags: host, nmap, discovery

I want to remotely examine if some servers are up.

I don't use the ping command because it gives a lot of wrong results like "destination host unreachable" and "request Timed out" due to bad networking infrastructure.

I try to use nmap command to examine servers by open ports. Nmap gives me the real opened ports, but when I turn off the server and the access point, nmap still reports it running.

I connects to the internet through a usb modem, and the destination host that I examine is connected to the internet through a TP-Link Access point with usb modem and a static IP.

When I turn off the remote access point completely and I run this command on my local machine :

```
nmap -p 80 -vv 105.198.224.47 

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-01-31 11:54 EET

Initiating Ping Scan at 11:54

Scanning 105.198.224.47 [2 ports]

Completed Ping Scan at 11:54, 0.61s elapsed (1 total hosts)

Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 11:54

Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 11:54, 0.01s elapsed

Initiating Connect Scan at 11:54

Scanning 105.198.224.47 [1 port]

Discovered open port 80/tcp on 105.198.224.47

Completed Connect Scan at 11:54, 0.09s elapsed (1 total ports)

Nmap scan report for 105.198.224.47

Host is up, received syn-ack (0.55s latency).

Scanned at 2017-01-31 11:54:17 EET for 0s

PORT   STATE SERVICE REASON

80/tcp open  http    syn-ack


Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.78 seconds
```

**And when put the ip in a browser it gives:**

```
"This site can’t be reached"

"The connection was reset."
```

This happens in both situations when it is turned on and turned off, However i don't setup any http server on the host.

**traceroute when the access point is turned on gives:**

```
traceroute to 105.198.224.47 (105.198.224.47), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets

 1  192.168.9.1 (192.168.9.1)  1.667 ms  1.768 ms  2.508 ms

 2  * * *

 3  10.255.224.106 (10.255.224.106)  759.425 ms  769.911 ms  770.401 ms

 4  10.255.224.114 (10.255.224.114)  770.142 ms  770.508 ms  770.871 ms

 5  10.255.224.124 (10.255.224.124)  771.866 ms  771.859 ms  779.227 ms

 6  105.199.1.3 (105.199.1.3)  780.458 ms  792.637 ms  792.453 ms

 7  163.121.143.88 (163.121.143.88)  803.571 ms  51.573 ms  41.250 ms

 8  163.121.143.75 (163.121.143.75)  49.261 ms  49.264 ms  49.384 ms

 9  * * *

10  * * *

11  * * *

12  * * *

13  * * *

14  * * *

15  * * *

16  * * *

17  * * *

18  * * *

19  * * *

20  * * *

21  * * *

22  * * *

23  * * *

24  * * *

25  * * *

26  * * *

27  * * *

28  * * *

29  * * *

30  * * *
```

running traceroute when the access point turned off gives the same result but the changes only in values of milli seconds ms.

So, what the explanation of this behaviour?

Comment: Probably your ISP is sending bogus responses to you. This sort of thing isn't always reliable on satellite or 3G connections.

Comment: Do you think a way to ensure that this behaviour is from ISP ?  is there is any cache or any buffer i should flush it ?

Comment: I actually notice this same behavior on local networks sometimes... depending on nmap's configuration, a whole /24 network will show up as having devices on all 254 available addresses, when I know for a fact there`s only 3.